# MVC3 WebGrid column definition problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a WebGrid in one of my views, in one of the columns i want to show a image if the user is a leader. What I have thus far, doesn't work at the moment. Anyone know how I can do this?

The code of my troublerow:

```
grid.Column("FullName", header:"Name", format: (item) => (item.IsLeader())) ?
    @<text><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Leader.gif")" alt="" /></text> :
    Html.ActionLink((string)item.FullName,"Index","Organization", new { area = "Catalogue" }, null)
),
```

Im getting overload error.
Hope everyone can see what I want to be done here. (Im new to razor and WebGrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Func<dynamic, object> format = @<text>@{ 
    if (item.IsLeader())
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Leader.gif")" alt="" />
    }
    else
    {
        <text>Html.ActionLink((string)@item.FullName,"Index","Organization", new { area = "Catalogue" }, null).ToString()</text>;
    }}</text>;

grid.Column(
    "FullName", 
    header:"Name", 
    format: format            
)
```

See more about delegates in Razor here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

Comment: Didn't work, I don't think you can write the razor syntax like that inside a webgrid definition

Comment: Sorry, yes :) Slight modification should work though, no? just take it out the definition into some variable.

Comment: Do you have an example? I've tried probably 50 ways up to now :P

Comment: That wont work, as the "item" variable belongs to Webgrid, i cant define new variables inside of webgrid, and i cant use item outside the webgrid definition (as it doesnt exist).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3100/discussion-between-michael-sagalovich-and-serrghi)